# 'Grotty' man page messages

Tags: grep, manpage

If I try to search within certain man pages using grep, I get several 'grotty' messages.

For example:

```
man mpv | grep dvdnav
```

results in:

```
mpv dvdnav://[longest|menu|title][/device] [options]
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):90690: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):90694: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):90698: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):90702: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):91895: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):91899: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):91903: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):91907: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):94450: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):94454: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (<standard input>):94458: character above first line discarded
                                                  │dvdnav://              │ dvdnav://menu                         │
```

What causes these messages and how do I prevent them?

Comment: This happens when the man page is NOT uncompressed first. Check if there is a `/etc/man.conf`; if present and empty delete it and try your command again. If present and not empty post results of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no `mpv` installed, but this seems more a warning of `grotty` (the program that process man page sources to print it to standard output) probably coming from no-compliant man pages. Have you tried

```
man mpv 2> /dev/null | grep dvdnav
```

? This will redirect error and warnings from `grotty` to the sink, so that you should have a cleaner output.

Nevertheless, that error is probably a bug in the `mpv` man page (or in `grotty`, you never know).

Answer (score 0):

**I'm pretty sure this is being caused by a bug in the man page text formatter.**

[Update: Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38253755/man-page-grotty-error-character-above-first-line-discarded) answer w/ ref to [bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673436) report.]

`man grotty` says,

> grotty translates the output of GNU troff into a form suitable for
>   typewriter-like devices.

---

**To debug this** first, check if you can also display this man page with `groffer` (graphical roffer).

When I ran into these errors, I found that groffer worked fine, without the error, but grotty threw up this 'character above first line discarded' error.

---

So I dug a little deeper.  The page that was giving me the trouble was zoneminder.1.

First I unzipped it:

```
gunzip -k zoneminder.1.gz
```

Then using this I can run a test:

```
man -l man.1 | grep jksffjsd   #-l means man the local file, i.e. produce error messages
```

**Now edit zoneminder.1 with divide and conquer.**  First deleted the last 1/2 of it and the error went away.  Then deleted only the last 3/4 of it and the error was still there.  Then deleted the last 5/8 of it and the error was still there.  Then took a look at it and started to just remove a few lines at a time until the error toggled from on to off.

I found myself in a table, and could only delete some whole entries from the table (see image below).

What I found was that this table was what was messing up, **but only when it overflowed to the next page**, as is shown here:

[image]

Remove one more entry from the table and the errors go away.

---

So it's fair to just ignore this.

I'll see if I can report it as a bug in grotty.

Answer (score 0):

This is over 5 years old; I know. But if someone else is facing the same issue,  I've just answered a question like this; quite simply:
[How to use grep to search for options in a man page?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1281432/how-to-use-grep-to-search-for-options-in-a-man-page/1281435#1281435)

```
$ man ls | grep -- '--a'
     -a, --all
     -A, --almost-all
     --author
```

> And to narrow down the results to just lines starting with a hyphen:
>
> ```
> grep '^[[:space:]]*-' –
> ```

Test run:

```
$ man shutdown | grep -- '-' | grep '^[[:space:]]*-'
       --help
       -H, --halt
       -P, --poweroff
       -r, --reboot
       -h
       -k
```